# SEO search result indentation (google)

Tags: web, seo

I want my website to have indentation in google result search. 
After taking reference of many websites, I found this one website "www.traveloka.com"

Inside the website, I can't find any meta keywords stuffs. 
But the website is well indented.

My question is : 
- does meta keywords really needed to have google indent my search result ? 
- if yes, why the website www.traveloka.com is well indented without meta keywords ? 
- if no, what matters then ? Beside having the page have href linking to each other ?

UPDATE : 
While doing SEO, I found this website : 
[chlooe.com](http://chlooe.com) 
It reports SEO advises, which ones to be changed, etc. 
I'll follow the instructions there. any thoughts ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by indentation you mean [image: this]... it's called sublinks.

Meta tags are no longer important for most search engines. They now rank the pages according to content so in your site's content, use strong keywords to get better ranking.

Having a specific page title helps a lot too.

As for the meta tags, personally, I like to leave it in but they are no longer mandatory.

The Google site links are generated automatically by Google depending on your content.

Here are a few tips:

1) Have a sitemap.xml in your website. This will tell the crawlers which pages are available on your site. To generate a sitemap.xml, I use http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/

2) Submit that sitemap to [google webmaster tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/).

3) Use clean urls. For example www.mydomain.com/contact, .../about-us, .../portfolio, ... etc. These help search engines seperate the content and create sub links depending on the most important content.

4) Most important of all, get traffic on your website... no traffic = poor ranking.

This is not a full tutorial but just some tips. Search for "google sub links" to learn more.

Hope this helps

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en

Comment: vyx, I tried your advises, and yeah it did work. Sublinks shows up 2 links. But after a while, the sublinks are gone. And sometimes it can show up one day and gone the other day. Is this normal ?

Comment: I can't say that it's normal but surely not unheard of. The Google algorithm is very complex and keeps updating so it's hard to say why it's acting like that. I would wait a while longer and make sure your google webmaster site is well configured.